# Output from Oracle stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE A2CountSkus
(v_count out Number )
AS
 BEGIN 
   SELECT count(*)
      INTO v_count
      FROM a2sku;
   EXCEPTION 
 When Others THEN
    RAISE;
END A2CountSkus;
```

When I run this script.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SKU COUNT ' || A2CountSkus); 
END; 
/
```

Instead of output being printed it gives an error.

Comment: **What** error does it give you?

Comment: @Mat Error starting at line 2 in command:
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SKU COUNT ' || to_char(A2COUNTSKUS())); 
END; 
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 46:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'A2COUNTSKUS'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: "wrong number or types of arguments in call " - doesn't that tell you what's wrong?

Comment: @Mat v_count is output parameter. What I have to pass so that the required input get printed when I run the 2nd script. Thanks.

Comment: It's an out _parameter_. You need to pass a parameter to store the value into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, normally, if you have a named PL/SQL block whose only purpose is to return a value, you would declare a function rather than a procedure.  If you had declared `A2CountSkus` as a function that returned a number, the syntax that you want to use would work.

Second, you do not want that exception clause-- it does nothing useful.  It should be eliminated.

Third, if you do want the block to be a procedure, the caller would need to declare a local variable that can be passed in to the procedure and then print the value in the local variable.

If you want to declare a function

```
create or replace FUNCTION A2CountSkus
  return integer
AS
  l_count integer;
BEGIN 
  SELECT count(*)
    INTO l_count
    FROM a2sku;
  RETURN l_count;
END A2CountSkus;
```

If you are sure that you want to declare a procedure, the caller would need to be something like

```
DECLARE
  l_count integer;
BEGIN 
  A2CountSkus( l_count );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SKU COUNT ' || l_count); 
END;
```